# Why can int not be used as an l-value of a return type while a user-defined class can?

Tags: c++, function, types, return-type, lvalue

```
struct A {};

A f1()
{
    return A();
}

int f2()
{
    return int();
}

int main()
{
    f1() = A();   // OK
    f2() = int(); // error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
}
```

Why is `f1() = A();` OK while `f2() = int();` is failed?

Comment: Because the designers decided so.

Comment: Historically speaking, it's because lvalue expressions designate locations in memory ("objects"), whereas rvalue expressions don't (they have values). There's such a thing as an `int` value that is not an object (has no address), but there's no such thing as a value of class type that is not an object (for technical reasons that I'm not wholly sure of, but aside from anything else what would `this` be?). As the answers below indicate, the terminology got a bit more complicated from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function f1 returns a rvalue, which might become an xvalue (an “eXpiring” value). The function f2 returns a builtin type which is an rvalue becomming an prvalue (“pure” rvalue).

From 3.10 [Lvalues and rvalues]

> — An xvalue (an “eXpiring” value) also refers to an object, usually
>   near the end of its lifetime (so that its resources may be moved, for
>   example). An xvalue is the result of certain kinds of expressions
>   involving rvalue references (8.3.2).

Hence, due to an implicit move operation the assignment of A becomes valid.

Changing A to:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A& operator = (const A&) { return *this; }
};
```

produces: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’ with g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2

Comment: The deleted constructor is called in the statement `return A();`, not in the statement `f1() = A();` As per [expr]/7 (a non-mandatory note), none of the expressions here is an xvalue. [expr.call]/10 explicitly states "A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function
type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise." Therefore both `f1()` and `f2()` yield a prvalue.

Answer (score 3):

`f1()` returns an instance of `A`. Since you haven't overwritten the copy/move-assignment operator, the compiler generates one for you. You're essentially calling a member function:

```
f1() = A(); // calls A& operator=(A&&)
```

The second doesn't work because `int` is not of class type.